# Applies f to all locations other than the specified location

Tags: functions, map

```
MapAt[f, <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>, Except["b"]]
```

I want to apply the function `f` everywhere except at `"b"`, but the code above obviously doesn't work. Of course, I can realize it by following code:

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>;
MapAt[f, assoc,Position[Keys@assoc, Except["b"], {1}, Heads -> False]]
```

> <|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> 2, "c" -> f[3], "d" -> f[4]|>

But, Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Association[{f /@ assoc, KeyTake[assoc, "b"]}]

AssociationMap[If[#[[1]] == "b", #, MapAt[f, #, -1]] &, assoc]

Merge[{f /@ assoc, KeyTake[assoc, "b"]}, #[[-1]] &]

MapAt[f, assoc, List /@ Cases[Keys@assoc, Except["b"]]]
```

Comment: More concise a little:`<|f/@assoc,KeyTake[assoc,"b"]|>`

Answer (score 7):

#### 1.

```
ClearAll[mapWithExceptions]
mapWithExceptions[a_, f_, e_] := MapAt[f, a, Map[List] @ Keys @ KeyDrop[e] @ a]
```

***Examples:***

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>;

mapWithExceptions[assoc, h, "b"]
```

> ```
>  <|"a" -> h[1], "b" -> 2, "c" -> h[3], "d" -> h[4]|>
> ```

```
mapWithExceptions[assoc, h, {"a", "c"}]
```

> ```
>  <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> h[2], "c" -> 3, "d" -> h[4]|>
> ```

```
mapWithExceptions[assoc, #^2 &, {"a", "c"}]
```

> ```
>  <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 4, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 16|>
> ```

#### 2.

```
mapExceptAt = Apply[Join] @* Through @* {Map @ #, KeyTake @ #2} &;
```

***Examples:***

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>;

mapExceptAt[g, "b"] @ assoc
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> g[1], "b" -> 2, "c" -> g[3], "d" -> g[4]|>
> ```

```
mapExceptAt[10 + #^2 &, "b"]@assoc
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 11, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 19, "d" -> 26|>
> ```

```
mapExceptAt[h, {"a", "c"}] @ assoc
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> h[2], "c" -> 3, "d" -> h[4]|>
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
dt = Map[f, <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>];

MapAt[Apply[Identity], "b"] @ dt
```

or

```
ReplaceAt[f[x_] :> x , "b"] @ dt
```

[image]

Comment: In general, `Apply[Identity]` does not _undo_ `f`'s action, Take, for example, f`= Sqrt`.

Comment: Good observation. In this case one could post-process with `// Map[ReplaceAll[f -> Sqrt]]`

Answer (score 0):

My version of the `mapWithExceptions` function using `AssociationMap` is as follows:

```
mapWithExceptions[a_Association, f_, e_] := 
AssociationMap[With[{k = #[[1]], v = #[[2]]}, If[! FreeQ[e, k], k -> v, k -> f[v]]] &, a]
```

An example:

```
assoc = <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|>;
mapWithExceptions[assoc, f, "b"]

<|"a" -> f[1], "b" -> 2, "c" -> f[3], "d" -> f[4]|>
```